# Divisibility problem involving the $2015^{th}$ power

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Show that the number $$ (5+2\sqrt6)^{2015} + (5-2\sqrt6)^{2015} - 10$$ is divisible by $960$.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you at least factored $960$ to break it into problems for each prime?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: The binomial theorem is the key. Note that if you work separately modulo $64, 3, 5$ most of the terms cancel out and you are left to the first summands.

Comment: Ok, I will give you a complete answer, leaving you some details.

Comment: Can you show that the expression is an integer at all?  Can you show that the expression is divisible by $5$?

Answer (score 3):

Well, the sequence $a_n=(5+2\sqrt6)^n+(5-2\sqrt6)^n-10$ must follow some linear recurrence relation like $a_n=10a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+80$ with initial conditions $a_1=0,\;a_2=88$, and every other of these seems to be divisible by 960, which should be easy to prove by induction.

Comment: Nice. Better to do the recurrence for odd terms directly though.

Comment: @Imawesome Your $n$ is now only counting the odd ones of the original sequence.  Think it should be $98a_n-a_{n-2}+960$ - double check.  Anyway the important thing is the constant term, which is divisible by $960$, so inductively every term is, starting with base case of $a_1 = 0, a_2 = 960$.

Answer (score 1):

Your number $+10$ is equal to
$$\sum_{k=0}^{2015} \binom{2015}{k} 5^{2015-k} (2 \sqrt{6})^k + \sum_{k=0}^{2015} \binom{2015}{k} 5^{2015-k} (-1)^k(2 \sqrt{6})^k$$
Now, when $k$ is odd the terms sum to $0$ so you are left to even terms, i.e.
$$2 \cdot \sum_{m=0}^{1007} \binom{2015}{2m} 5^{2015-2m} (2 \sqrt{6})^{2m}$$
where $2m=k$ are the even terms of the previous sum. This is equal to
$$2 \cdot \sum_{m=0}^{1007} \binom{2015}{2m} 5^{2015-2m} 8^m3^m$$
Now, for $m \neq 0,1$ the number
$$5^{2015-2m} 8^m3^m$$
is divisible by $5$, by $64=8^2$ and by $3$. So we are left to the first two terms
$$2 \cdot \binom{2015}{0} 5^{2015} + 2 \cdot \binom{2015}{2} 5^{2013} \cdot 24 = 5^{2013} \cdot 2 (5^2 + 2015 \cdot 1007 \cdot 24)$$
Clearly this is divisible by $5$. Modulo $3$ this is
$$(-1)^{2013}(-1)(1+0) \equiv 1 \equiv 10 \mod{3}$$
while modulo $64$ we have to work harder.

Comment: But its $-10$??

Comment: It's $a-10$, so if you add $10$ you get $a$.